# unwanted html created in table td while clicking the checkbox in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

i work with nopCommerce 3.0 source code in the vs 2012 ultimate edition.

currently i working in the Nop.Admin project with telirik grid. Now i face a issue in

click event of checkbox control in the telirik grid.

There is a checkbox tag in every telirik grid row. when the user is checked in the checkbox

i push the value of the checkbox to a array. this is done by jQuery part.

***(Please Note : I alredy do this project in the NopCommerce 2.30. currently i try to upgrade 
the nopCommerce 2.30 source code to nopCommerce 3.00 source code. This code is works fine
in my nopCommerce 2.30 source code.)***

Please see the below images .

**Before the click.**

[image]

Before click there no additional code in between the **td** cell.

**After the click.**

[image]

Now there are more strange html comes in between the **td** cell.

How can i solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I remove the

```
.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
```

code in my razor.